# Jenkins not connecting to AWS EC2 instance via SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to connect to an `EC2 instance` from `Jenkins` via `SSH`. I always get failure in the end. I am storing the `SSH key` in a `global credential`.

> This is the task and shell, using SSH agent plugin

[image: 1]

> This is how I store the key (the whole key has been pasted in)

[image: 2]

If I am using SSH connection from my local PC, everything is fine. I am a newbie in Jenkins so this is very chaotic for me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use SSH plugin . download the plugin using Manage Jenkins and configure
the ec2 in SSH remote.
follow the steps in this link

```
https://www.thesunflowerlab.com/blog/jenkins-aws-ec2-instance-ssh/
```